# The correct use of "their" when I do not know the gender of the person

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

I have written the following sentence in an essay:

> There are more jobs in large cities, but in small towns you can live
> in peace. Which option a **person** chooses depends, to some extent, on
> **their** personality.

- Is it correct to use "their" in this sentence?
- Should I use "his or her"?
- Which one is better "their" or "his or her"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stodgy old prescriptivists will insist that "their" is always plural, and only "his or her" is correct here. If you're not writing for such a person likely to think less of you for such a thing, I would recommend just going with "their," which is briefer and more gender neutral anyway. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they).

Comment: Also, yes, your usage is correct